# Angular 7 Laravel 5.7 set-cookies is not possible

Tags: php, ajax, angular, laravel, cookies

I work on Single Page Application in Angular 7, and for REST server I use Laravel 5.7. Problem is when I try to set cookies in response of request.

In Angular I send request like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
        withCredentials: true
    };
    const body = this.postDataHelper.jsonToURLEncoded({username: username, password: password});
    return this.http.post(serverUrl + 'login', body, this.httpOptions);
}
```

And in Laravel I send response like this:

```
if ($token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims)) {
    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'token' => $token))->withCookie(cookie()->forever('cookie_name', 'cookie_value'));
}
```

Problem is that I can't get Set-Cookie in response header in browser. When I try to send request over postman or phpstorm I get Set-Cookie in response header. So problem is with Angular I suppose.

Does anyone know how I can manipulate with cookies in response header, using Angular for frontend and Laravel for backend?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: In Mozilla works but in Chrome doesn't

Response header in Postman:

```
Server →nginx/1.15.0
Content-Type →application/json
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Connection →keep-alive
Cache-Control →no-cache, private
Date →Mon, 17 Dec 2018 19:47:34 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
X-RateLimit-Limit →60
X-RateLimit-Remaining →57
Set-Cookie →cookie_name=cookie_value; expires=Sat, 16-Dec-2023 19:47:34 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; path=/; httponly
```

As you can see on the end I get Set-Cookie in Postman, in Firefox too, but I can get that parameter in Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean with setting response in browser? Can you post response header example   or provide devtool response header?

Comment: I will edit question with response header, in Chrome that last Set-Cookie doesn't exist in response header in Chrome

Comment: You are missing ";" in the end there?

Comment: Where I was missing ";"?

Comment: Nvm, have you checked in devtool it's missing or are you checking in js angular response?

Comment: I checked in chrome console. Only solution I did found is to make proxy.config but that only works in developing, and I need solution for production too when front and back end are not on same domain.

Comment: Ah I see, try remove Httponly then as it might cause issues on different domains

Comment: It's not the solution. But it's a place for you to better understand what chrome does

Comment: I tried to remove httponly but without result, still should use proxy.config